# Modification of the code for listing items in the list

Tags: javascript

I have such an item in the points element.

```
<body>
Parent 1
Parent 2
Parent 3
    1st Child of 3
        1st grandchild
        2nd grandchild
    2nd Child of 3
    3rd Child of 3
Parent 4
    Parent 4's only child
</body>
```

I need to generate such a valid list using JavaScript.

```html
<ul class="tree">
    <li>Parent 1</li>
    <li>Parent 2</li>
    <li> Parent 3
        <ul>
            <li> 1st Child of 3
                <ul>
                    <li>1st grandchild</li>
                    <li>2nd grandchild</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>2nd Child of 3</li>
            <li>3rd Child of 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Parent 4
        <ul>
            <li>Parent 4's only child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried such a code among others but the code still doesn't work.

```
var bodyElement = document.body;
var bodyText = bodyElement.textContent;
bodyElement.textContent = '';
var outputDiv = document.createElement('div');
outputDiv.id = 'output';
document.body.appendChild(outputDiv);
var outputElement = document.getElementById('output');
var lines = bodyText.split('\n');
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.classList.add('tree'); // Přidáme třídu "tree" k ul elementu
var currentUl = ul;
var currentLi = null;
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    var indent = line.match(/^\t*/)[0].length; // Zjistíme počet tabulátorů na začátku řádku
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = line.trim(); // Odstraníme bílé znaky na začátku a konci řádku
    li.appendChild(span);
    if (indent === 0) {
        if (currentLi) {
            currentUl.appendChild(currentLi);
        }
        currentLi = li;
        ul.appendChild(currentLi);
        currentUl = document.createElement('ul');
        currentLi.appendChild(currentUl);
    } else {
        if (currentLi) {
            currentUl.appendChild(currentLi);
        }
        currentLi = li;
    }
}
if (currentLi) {
    currentUl.appendChild(currentLi);
}
outputElement.appendChild(ul);
```

I tried different variants, but I couldn't get it to work at all.

Comment: PSA: It's 2023 and time to learn about `let` and `const` in preference to `var`.

Comment: "Couldn't get it to work" needs more technical detail. Do you get any errors? Does it do *anything*? You create a lot of things here, but do you ever push them back into the DOM?

Comment: @tadman: I get this error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent. The error is on this line: 'currentUl.appendChild(currentLi);'

Comment: in my personal opinion, I find it a lot easier to build the markup in form of a string: https://jsfiddle.net/w1pgLvxb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically use a stack for keeping track of the indents.

```js
let li = document.body, ul;
const stack = [-1];
for (const line of document.body.firstChild.textContent.match(/.*\S/g)) {
    const indent = line.length - line.trim().length;
    while (stack.at(-1) >= indent) {
        stack.pop();
        li = li.parentNode.parentNode;
    }
    li.appendChild(ul = li.querySelector("ul") ?? document.createElement("ul"));
    ul.appendChild(li = document.createElement("li"));
    li.textContent = line.trim();
    stack.push(indent);    
}
document.body.firstChild.remove();
document.body.querySelector("ul").classList.add("tree");
```

```css
.tree { background: pink }
```

```html
Parent 1
Parent 2
Parent 3
    1st Child of 3
        1st grandchild
        2nd grandchild
    2nd Child of 3
    3rd Child of 3
Parent 4
    Parent 4's only child
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help. May it prosper.